# How to configure import mode for PBIRS report?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

Does power bi report server paginated report (made via report builder) support import mode?

Does power bi report server normal report (made via power bi desktop) support import mode?

Comment: Can you clarify what import mode is? Thank you

Comment: Import mode means the data is queried and held on the report, until it is then refreshed at regular intervals or manually.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI supports [Import Mode and Direct Query Mode](https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/06/21/power-bi-import-vs-direct-query/).

If the paginated report is pulling the data from a Power BI dataset **that** dataset can support both modes.

Comment: So paginated report by itself (I mean if data source of paginated report is SQL server) can only use direct query?

Comment: No, it can support both as far as  understand. Because I don't see why a paginated report should behave differently form a normal visual inside Power BI

Comment: When I add SQL datasource to a paginated report, then at each run it makes a fresh query to the SQL db. That means it's a direct query type of a report. Is there any way to make it behave like an import mode?